# I need help with polynomial long division

Tags: polynomials

When proving $2^n - 1$ is composite if $n$ is composite this product $(x^a-1)(x^{(a-1)b} + x^{(a-2)b} + x^{(a-3)b} + ... + x^a + 1) = x^{ab} - 1$ comes up. I am not sure how to verify this by long division. For example, $\frac {x^{ab}}{x^a} = x^{ab - a}$ whereas the first term in the second factor of $x^{ab} - 1$ is $x^{(a-1)b}$. Please, comment on how to do this long division.

Comment: You have quoted the wrong factorization. Review your work and come back.

Comment: You know that $x^a=1$ is a factor because $(x^a)^b = 1$ thus satisfying the equation. But dp you want to verify the second bracket? The expansion?

Comment: @ Matt Samuel, Here's the link to what we did elsewhere http://www.reddit.com/r/cheatatmathhomework/comments/34vi0n/prove_that_2n_1_is_composite_if_n_is_composite/

Comment: You need $x^{a(b-1)}+x^{a(b-2)}\dots$ and it all works out

Comment: @ Mark Bennet, Is the given factorization incorrect?

Comment: No, the exponents should decrease by $a$ each step, not by $b$

Comment: @veryinoffensive: yes, the factorization listed in your question is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, with reducing the power of $x^a$ at each stage until you arrive at $x^0=1$ which cancels the $-1$ at the end (or do an induction):

$x^{ab}-1=(x^a-1)x^{a(b-1)}+x^{a(b-1)}-1=(x^a-1)x^{a(b-1)}+(x^a-1)x^{a(b-2)}+x^{a(b-2)}-1=\dots $

Comment: @veryinoffensive: note the difference between this factorization and the one you've listed; in particular, terms like $x^{a(b-1)}$ vs. $x^{(a-1)b}$...

Comment: I like this solution. Perfect.